# How to use "comparison" for without?

Tags: american-english, comparison

I was developed a method. In my method, I was divided it into scheme A and without scheme A. I want to use the word "comparison" to compare my proposed method when I use scheme A and without scheme A. This is my sentence

> The proposed method with scheme A allows to maintain the quality comparison with the proposed method without scheme A.

However, the above sentence look wrong grammar as well as not professional way. Could you help me to improve my above sentence. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your intent, I would write:

> The proposed method *with/using* scheme A allows *you* to maintain the quality **compared** with the proposed method *without/not using* scheme A.

*compare* used here is a verb.

To use *comparison*, you might say somethink like:

> The quality **comparison** of the proposed methods, with and without scheme A, is ...

*comparison* used here is a noun.

Comment: For "comparison" could I write a full sentence based on your suggestion as "The quality comparison of the proposed methods, with and without scheme A, is maintained". The first sentence the word "the proposed method" is repeated twice times. Is it possible to ignore it

Comment: Yes that is fine.